# How to implement keyword Hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

English Science Mathematics-It should go to A
Science Mathematics - It should go to B
Mathematics- It should go to C

Suppose I have a description as below

```
I like english science mathematics   
Science Mathematics are my favourite  
I hate Mathematics
```

then I should get result as below

```
Column Description                      Category
I like english science mathematics      A
Science Mathematics are my favourite    B
I hate Mathematics                      C
```

Comment: Use `CHARINDEX` or `LIKE` expressions? [so] isn't a free coding service; what have ***you*** tried? Why didn't it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case`:

```
select (case when column like '%Mathematics%' and
                  column like '%Science%' and
                  column like '%English%' 
             then 'A'
             when column like '%Mathematics%' and
                  column like '%Science%'
             then 'B'
             when column like '%Mathematics%' 
             then 'C'
        end)
```

Comment: Ye Olde token parsing problem: "Englishmen embrace science and mathematics." isn't category "A". Or is it?

Comment: @Habo . . . I don't know.  You should ask the OP.